# How to create root routes without displaying controller name in link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I was just wondering if anybody can point me to right direction. Here's my problem:

I have a controller in Controllers folder called Events, and there I have some ActonResult methods Index, Search, Details, which returns Views from the

> View/Events/Index,Search,Details

and some partial views from shared folder.

Now what will be the best way to display those Views without controllers name. My index view is now displayed as

> localhosts|domain.com.../Events/Index or localhosts|domain.com.../Events/Details/1

and I wan't to be displayed as

> localhosts|domain.com... or localhosts|domain.com.../Details/1

Now, I am curious if those changes will have any effects for my AJAX calls which are:

just part of a js code

`@Url.Action("index", "Events"),`

and

`url: "@Url.Content("~/Events/MyAjaxSearch")",
       data: "searchString=test&Location=test",`

I also have some params in my Index method for pageNum(this is for infinite pagination).

Bellow is my RouteConfig code:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.MapRoute("Events", "", new { controller = "Events", action = "Index" });
      routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "EventDetails",
       url: "Details/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `action = "Details"` in the defaults?

Comment: Thanks, it's changed

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working, and so is Ajax. Now one little question. How about if I just write down the domain... Let's say test.azurewebsites.net and that this will also display Index view.

Comment: Domain shouldn't be part of route mappings.